# Laravel Eloquent: Save a Model and a relation within a single Database Transaction

Tags: database, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, transactions

I have the following 2 database (psql) tables defined as below:

> ```
> create table product
> (
>     date date default CURRENT_DATE not null,
>     updated_at timestamp(0) default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) not null,
>     product_id integer not null
> )
>
>
> create table product_offer
> (
>     date date default CURRENT_DATE not null,
>     updated_at timestamp(0) default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) not null,
>     product_id integer not null,
>     offer_id integer not null,
>     price decimal,
>     constraint product_fkey
>         foreign key (date, updated_at, product_id) references product
> )
> ```

In Laravel, I have the models setup and the relationship defined as follows:

> ```
> public function offers()
>     {
>         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Offer', 'product_offer', 'product_id', 'offer_id')
>                     ->withPivot('date', 'updated_at','price');
>     }
> ```

I am attempting to create a new Product and attach an offer to it within a single transaction:

> ```
> $product = new Product; 
> $product->product_id = 1; 
> $offers = [1 => ['price' => 10]];
>
> DB::beginTransaction();  
> try {
>     $product->save();
>     $product->offers()->attach($offers);
>     DB::commit();  
> } catch (\Exception $e) {
>     DB::rollback();  
> }
> ```

But I get the following error from the database:

> SQLSTATE[23503]: Foreign key violation: 7 ERROR:  insert or update on
>   table "product_offer" violates foreign key constraint "product_fkey"
>   DETAIL:  Key (date, updated_at, product_id)=(2020-05-19, 2020-05-19
>   12:19:47, 1) is not present in table "product".

Could you please let me know what would be the best way to troubleshoot this? Would it be possible that the statements within the transaction are executed out of order? Or is possible that the save() method will commit the transaction prematurely?

Please note that the code above works **on occasion**. For example, if I make 10 attempts, 50% of the time the transaction is successful and the rest I get the error above.

Comment: First: I think your foreign key constraint is not right, second: why not use Laravel migration tables its much easier.

Comment: In my experience $product->save() does not complete at DB server level before $product->offer() is fired. To make a compromise I reload $product from DB before $product->offer().... script. For instance I do a $product->fresh() after $product->save()

Comment: @nikistag That's what I thought and I changed the foreign key constraint to be deferrable to the commit of the transaction but the issue persists. Also, without any changes, this works sometimes and other times it doesn't which makes think that the Laravel transaction handling is not consistent.

Comment: Refreshing my model solved my problem... what about yours?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel will expect your primary key to be 'id'. If you're using something other than 'id', it will need to be defined on the model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions